# What make and model is this 386 mainboard?

Tags: identify-this-computer, 80386

I have received a 386 mainboard with OPTI chipset. Possibly an early model, since it does not support cache.

The chipset is labeled "82C381P" and "Chipset2".

[image: OPTi 386 Mainboard]

Comment: She's a beauty. Looks Taiwanese to me. Take her measurements and find her a nice tower to live in.

Comment: Are there any other markings on the board itself?  That may be a clue to helping figure out the manufacturer/model.

Comment: Also, what speed is the board?  I'm guessing 25Mhz or 33Mhz?

Comment: I can't find any markings on the board. On the back is a four digit number, but that looks pretty generic. The CPU is 33 MHz.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is my best guess, but it looks really close.  Could it be a Gigabyte GA-386PS?

This block diagram looks very similar:

[image]

I couldn't find the actual manual, but there are some jumper setting and connector details [here](http://stason.org/TULARC/pc/motherboards/G/GIGA-BYTE-TECHNOLOGY-CO-LTD-386-GA-386PS.html)

Comment: This looks really close!

Comment: I wonder what S1 is. It is supposedly a memory card slot... a quick search turned up nothing.

Comment: @Arne It seems to be a slot for external cache (Gigabyte-specific). Odd that it's so far from the CPU though.

Comment: I think it would be remiss not to start from the observation that S1 has the exact same pin count and layout as the 16-bit ISA slots. That could just be because they were ordering those connectors anyway, of course.

Comment: @Tommy A few things make me think it's for cache.  1) The 386 could use external cache modules  2) The modules weren't standardized  3) Gigabyte (still) offers a cache configuration utility for download (this implies that cache is supported but not included on the board)  4) There don't appear to be any cache memory chips on the board  5) The slot is right by the DRAMs  6) The linked document claims this is a 32-bit slot which seems sensible for cache of that era

Comment: @Tommy You're probably right that using the same connector (reversed) was used to cut part costs.  IIRC, the same was done with PCI → AGP.

Comment: Oh dear, if we could get a pinout of that connector, one could probably design a PCB and populate it with SRAMs to make a custom cache module...

Comment: @Arne On a board like that you could probably determine the pinout with a continuity tester

Comment: On the documentation, S1 is labeled "32-bit external memory card". I doubt it is for cache specifically. It is probably just a way to extend the DRAM (and since it is close to the RAM slots...)

Comment: @dim Per the linked doc, the board has 8 slots (across 2 banks, each slot stores 1 byte of each word) and supports a maximum of 8 MB of RAM (2 banks of 4×1MB SIMMs).  I suppose one could hang something else off that bus but my instinct is still that it's solely for cache.

Comment: @alex actually, I found [other pictures of this mainboard](http://www.peters-paradise.org/Fotos/Archiviert/Mainboards/Gigabyte%20GA-386PS/) (which confirms Geo's answer BTW), where we can see the component part numbers. One of the chip: OPTI 82C381 is labeled "system and cache memory controller" in another [document](https://www.scribd.com/document/81301233/Chip-Sets#) so you are probably right...

Comment: @dim Nice find.  Interesting to see how many 74 series chips are on the board alongside the VLSI ones.

Comment: @AlexHajnal I can take closeup pictures - if wanted - of the ICs used on the board.

Comment: @Arne No need, the pics you linked to are great.  Just found the mix of chip complexities interesting (the 74-series are all simple buffers, line drivers, and the like).  I'd love to see where the traces run but alas I suspect it's probably a multi-layer board (at the very least there are traces on the back side) so even a back-side photo probably wouldn't show much.  You haven't found a schematic have you?